# WebPack 2: Replaced require'd module with global

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-2

Working on a set of scripts that will run in a browser context where certain modules (e.g. underscore) will be available as global modules. However, I'm depending on modules in `node_modules` that `require` / `import` underscore directly. Is it possible to configure WebPack to depend on the global underscore instance when compiling these files instead of duplicating that library in my compiled scripts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for are [Externals](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/):

> `externals` configuration in webpack provides a way of not including a dependency in the bundle. Instead the created bundle relies on that dependency to be present in the consumers environment. This typically applies to library developers though application developers can make good use of this feature too.

This even works for modules in `node_modules`, as webpack walks the *entire* dependency tree to figure out what to include in the resulting bundle.

There's even an [example](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/#object) that's specifically for your use case, it looks like:

```
externals : {
    lodash : {
    commonjs: "lodash",
    amd: "lodash",
    root: "_" // indicates global variable
  }
}
```

> This syntax is used to describe all the possible ways that an external library can be available. lodash here is available as lodash under AMD and CommonJS module systems but available as _ in a global variable form.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rely on a library already being available in the environment when your bundle is loaded, you need to make use of [externals](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/).

```
module.exports = {
    externals: {
        underscore: "_"
    }
}
```

The key of the object (`underscore`) is what you use to import it, and the value (`_`) is the global variable it will look for.

```
require("underscore"); // Will return the _ variable from the global environment!
```